# angular 2 event emitter is not working properly

Tags: angular

I have two components. one is bottom-nav component it will act child component and another is dashboard component this will act parent component, below code I have to use, just click child component setting icon when setActive fucntion will call then I need some alert in parent component.

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
===== html part ======
<div class="left-wrapper hide">
    <app-right-nav id="slide" (bottomClick)="menuOpen()"></app-right-nav>
  </div>

===== typescript ======
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { BottomNavComponent } from '../bottom-nav/bottom-nav.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
  providers: [BottomNavComponent]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  menuOpen() {
    alert('test');
    $(".left-wrapper").removeClass('hide');
    $(".left-wrapper").addClass('show');
  }

}
```

**bottom-nav.component.ts**

```
========= html part ========
<div id="bottom-navigation">
  <div class="bottom-icon active" id="home" (click)="setActive('home')">
    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
    <p>Home</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-icon" id="location" (click)="setActive('location')">
    <mat-icon>location_on</mat-icon>
    <p>Near by</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-icon" id="history" (click)="setActive('history')">
    <mat-icon>history</mat-icon>
    <p>History</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-icon" id="settings"  (click)="setActive('settings')">
    <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
    <p>Settings</p>
  </div>
</div>

======= typescript ========
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bottom-nav',
  templateUrl: './bottom-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bottom-nav.component.scss']
})
export class BottomNavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @Input() count:any = 0;

  @Output() bottomClick:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  setActive(idname:any) {
    $(".bottom-icon").removeClass('active');
    $("#"+idname).addClass('active');

    if(idname == 'settings') {
      this.count++;
      this.bottomClick.emit(this.count);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: The two components you posted are completely unrelated: the one that is supposed to be a child has the selector 'app-bottom-nav', but the parent component uses `<app-right-nav>`. Also, **remove jQuery**. Stop using jQuery to modify the DOM. Change the state of your component and use binding to add/remove classes.

Comment: thank you and sorry

Comment: I changed above but not working again

Answer (score 1):

Your child component selector is app-bottom-nav but in parent code you use "app-right-nav".

So change and solve this problem to see if it dose not work.